# Pasar registros de una tabla a otra con sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo instalado Oracle 11g Express con el editor de SQL DEVELOPER, quiero insertar registros de una tabla a otra con una sola instrucción, el problema es que mi tabla destino tiene una columna AUTOINCREMENT y la tabla origen no tiene columna AUTOINCREMENT, de la tabla origen solo tiene una columna y la tabla destino tiene una columna ID que es la llave primaria y es AUTOINCREMENT y 4 columnas mas, mi tabla destino no acepta nulos en ninguno de las columnas, de mi tabla origen requiero que los registros de la columna NUM_TELEFONO se inserten en mi tabla destino en la columna IDENTIFICADOR, no debe ser con procedimiento almacenado, muestro ejemplo de como lo tengo actual:

Mi tabla origen es CAT_BLOQUEO_TELEFONICO_MI(columnas: NUM_TELEFONO)
Mi tabla destino es TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO_MI (columnas: ID, IDENTIFICADOR, TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR, ID_USUARIO_ALTA, FECHA_ALTA)

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c_origen IS
       SELECT * FROM CAT_BLOQUEO_TELEFONICO_MI;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_origen;
     FOR R IN c_origen LOOP
         INSERT INTO TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO_MI(ID, IDENTIFICADOR)
         VALUES(SEQ_TBL_BL_REG_TEL_MI.NEXTVAL, R.NUM_TELEFONO);

     END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_origen;
END;
```

El error que muestra es:

> ORA-06511: PLSQL: cursor ya abierto
> ORA-06512: en linea 3
> ORA-06512: en linea 6
> 06511. 00000 - "PL/SQL: cursor already open"

La otra parte que intente hacer fue esto:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO(ID, IDENTIFICADOR)
    VALUES( (SELECT NVL(MAX(ID),0) + 1 FROM TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO),
    (SELECT NUM_TELEFONO FROM CAT_BLOQUEO_TELEFONICO_MI) );
END;
```

La otra forma para insertar registros en las demás columnas de mi tabla destino TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO_MI declaro variables que lleven valor por default, así me lo piden, entonces lo que hice fue esto.

```
DECLARE
    V_TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR NUMBER(1);
    V_ID_USUARIO_ALTA    VARCHAR(30);
    V_FECHA_ALTA         DATE;

    CURSOR c_origen IS
        SELECT * FROM CAT_BLOQUEO_TELEFONICO_MI;
BEGIN
    FOR R IN c_origen LOOP
        V_TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR := 2;
        V_ID_USUARIO_ALTA := 'H25';
        V_FECHA_ALTA := SYSDATE;
    
        INSET INTO TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO_MI(ID, IDENTIFICADOR, 
        V_TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR, V_ID_USUARIO_ALTA, V_FECHA_ALTA)
        VALUES(SEQ_TBL_BL_REG_TEL_MI.NEXTVAL, R.NUM_TELEFONO, 
        R.V_TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR, R.V_ID_USUARIO_ALTA, R.V_FECHA_ALTA);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Me piden que la fecha sea jalada directo del sistema por eso lleva SYSDATE, pero me manda un error en la columna fecha_alta, el error que sale es:

PLS-00302: el componente 'V_FECHA_ALTA' se debe declarar
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: columna no permitida aquí

Espero puedan ayudarme...

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: @gbianchi el problema es que marca error en el cursor, dice el error, que el cursor ya esta abierto: (ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor ya abierto) y a veces me dice también de que trato violar la llave primaria

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Los errores (los mensajes) se incluyen completos en la pregunta (ojalá como texto para no estar arrugando los ojos a ver qué dice la imagen). Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir toda la info relevante usando el enlace Editar que está bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas

Comment: Mi aproximación sería hacer INSERT INTO... SELECT en vez de lidiar con un cursor y gastar más tiempo haciendo lo mismo. Lo que no entiendo es por qué ese LOOP no funciona. Por favor, incluye explícitamente el error que da tu código. De paso, aclara si en la tabla destino hay alguna columna NOT NULL y si los tipos de dato en las columnas origen y destino son iguales.

Comment: @Alfabravo todas las columnas de mi tabla destino son NOT NULL, lo indique en la pregunta que hice, eso que comentas de hacer un INSERT INTO... SELECT ya lo he probado y no funciona, por que dice que trato de violar la clave primaria

Comment: Pues entonces estás insertando lo que no es donde no es. Incluye en tu pregunta cómo intentaste hacer el INSERT INTO para saber de dónde estás intentando sacar los demás campos NOT NULL que tiene tu tabla. Tu cursor tampoco va a funcionar porque te faltan los demás campos (a menos que tengan un valor DEFAULT ). Y por favor, incluye los mensajes de error completos, no una transcripción vaga

Comment: @Alfabravo mi tabla origen solo tiene una columna y es el mismo tipo de dato y también es NOT NULL al igual que mi tabla destino la columna es el mismo tipo de dato y es NOT NULL igual que la tabla origen, obvio como indique en la pregunta la tabla destino tiene mas columnas pero es este caso solo quiero pasar NUM_TELEFONO sus registro de la tabla origen a la tabla destino en la columna IDENTIFICADOR

Comment: @Alfabravo ese error que muestro en la pregunta es el error que se arroga

Comment: @Alfabravo tampoco soy un experto en PL/SQL por eso pido apoyo

Comment: Perdón si se leyó diferente, la cosa era sólo de indicar qué cosas no sabemos de este lado y son necesarias para saber cómo ayudarte. Aca sólo somos colegas ayudándonos y más que expertos, somos compañeros de sufrimiento :) A ver si con lo que añadiste puedo ayudar en algo

Answer (score 2):

Si usas el cursor, puedes elegir entre a) usar LOOP y no abrirlo (porque el LOOP abre el cursor). Por eso te dice que *Ey, ya está abierto*.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c_origen IS
       SELECT * FROM CAT_BLOQUEO_TELEFONICO_MI;
BEGIN
      FOR R IN c_origen LOOP
         INSERT INTO TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO_MI(ID, IDENTIFICADOR)
         VALUES(SEQ_TBL_BL_REG_TEL_MI.NEXTVAL, R.NUM_TELEFONO);

      END LOOP;
END;
```

O puedes abrirlo y cerrarlo para, dentro del LOOP, hacer FETCH

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c_origen IS
       SELECT * FROM CAT_BLOQUEO_TELEFONICO_MI;

   -- Una variable de tipo fila-de-la-tabla 
   cursor_row cat_bloqueo_telefonico_mi%rowtype;
BEGIN
      OPEN c_origen
      LOOP
         FETCH c_origen INTO cursor_row;
         INSERT INTO TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO_MI(ID, IDENTIFICADOR)
         VALUES(SEQ_TBL_BL_REG_TEL_MI.NEXTVAL, cursor_row.NUM_TELEFONO);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c_origen;
END;
```

Si usas INSERT INTO... SELECT, recomiendo que uses la secuencia (usar el MAX por cada fila es más caro! y además no es saludable ese hábito pensando en accesos concurrentes). Tu consulta actual siempre va a traer el mismo valor de ese MAX+1 (a menos que la tabla se modifique durante la ejecución, e igual, esta ejecución tiene bloqueo de lectura en la fila de la tabla...) y por eso te está diciendo *Ey, ya inserté ese ID antes, no sirve*. En MySQL y demás uno está habituado a los autoincrement; en Oracle es sano tener siempre una secuencia que se encargue de entregar el siguiente valor a usar. Entonces, podrías usar algo parecido a:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO(ID, IDENTIFICADOR)
    SELECT 
        SEQ_TBL_BL_REG_TEL_MI.NEXTVAL,
        NUM_TELEFONO 
        FROM CAT_BLOQUEO_TELEFONICO_MI
    ;
END;
```

---

EDITO: Las restricciones NOT NULL no son negociables. Esa decisión no es técnica sino de negocio. ¿Qué valor tiene sentido que pongas en los campos restantes para los que no tienen información? Puedes ajustar la definición de la tabla para que, adicional al NOT NULL, tengan un valor DEFAULT

```
CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name (
    column_1 data_type NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    column_2 data_type NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
    column_3 data_type NOT NULL DEFAULT misecuencia.nextval,
    ...
    table_constraint
 );
```

Pero no somos nosotros los encargados de decir con qué debes completar los datos. **Es una decisión de negocio** porque después vas a tener líos si le pones a todo `' '`, 1, 0 o cualquier otro valor que no llegó de los usuarios.

---

**SEGUNDA EDICIÓN:** Ya estás planteando una estructura más o menos válida.

Tu error está en que las variables que estás declarando no hacen parte de R, pues R tiene sólo lo que estás obteniendo de recorrer el cursor (una columna, la de toda la vida). Para evitar líos, yo aplicaría los campos adicionales, que son constantes, directamente en el INSERT (que además está mal escrito, `INSET`).

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_origen IS
        SELECT * FROM CAT_BLOQUEO_TELEFONICO_MI;
BEGIN
    FOR R IN c_origen LOOP
        INSERT INTO TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO_MI(ID, IDENTIFICADOR, 
        V_TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR, V_ID_USUARIO_ALTA, V_FECHA_ALTA)
        VALUES(SEQ_TBL_BL_REG_TEL_MI.NEXTVAL, R.NUM_TELEFONO, 
        2, 'H25', SYSDATE);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Y si por algún motivo quieres conservar las variables adicionales, no las trates como parte del cursor. Si no las vas a modificar dentro del loop, puedes asignarlas ANTES (y te ahorras tiempo al no asignar N veces el mismo valor a las mismas variables):

```
DECLARE
    V_TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR NUMBER(1);
    V_ID_USUARIO_ALTA    VARCHAR(30);
    V_FECHA_ALTA         DATE;

    CURSOR c_origen IS
        SELECT * FROM CAT_BLOQUEO_TELEFONICO_MI;
BEGIN
    V_TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR := 2;
    V_ID_USUARIO_ALTA := 'H25';

    FOR R IN c_origen LOOP   
        V_FECHA_ALTA := SYSDATE;

        INSERT INTO TBL_BL_REGISTRO_TELEFONICO_MI(ID, IDENTIFICADOR, 
        V_TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR, V_ID_USUARIO_ALTA, V_FECHA_ALTA)
        VALUES(SEQ_TBL_BL_REG_TEL_MI.NEXTVAL, R.NUM_TELEFONO, 
        V_TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR, V_ID_USUARIO_ALTA, V_FECHA_ALTA);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Alfabravo Los ejemplos son muy buenos, lo que pasa que como en mi tabla destino tengo 5 columnas que son NOT NULL, entonces a partir de la 3 columna de mi tabla destino me manda un error la consulta y dice "No se aceptan Nulos" y pues mi tabla origen solo tiene una columna, no se si hay alguna manera de que se puedan inserta los registros en mi tabla destino sin que me manda el error en las otras columnas de que no se acepan nulos.

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz ah, pero si eso es lo que te estaba preguntando. En ninguna parte de tu pregunta nos dices de dónde quieres sacar los datos que faltan (y me regañaste porque ya habías dicho que eran not null los campos de destino).

Comment: la cuestión es que no hay de donde sacar los demás datos, yo creo que debí crear mi tabla destino con las demás columnas que aceptaran valores nulos para que así me deje insertar los registros que quiero nada mas.

Comment: @JonathanOrtiz si puedes (tienes autorización, control sobre la BD) y debes (las consultas que hay no se dañan al hacerlo, los reportes no salen raros, etc) también es válido. Como indico en la pregunta, las restricciones en persistencia reflejan la naturaleza de los datos que produce el negocio

Comment: Alfabravo integre nueva consulta donde indico la forma de insertar registros en las demas columnas faltantes , pero me manda error en V_FECHA_ALTA me dice que debo declararla, puse igual el error que sale en BD esta en la pregunta, me piden que la fecha sea sysdate, no se que estoy haciendo mal con el error que me sale.